# Kohana 3 ORM - How to tell if the current model being saved is new?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

In my ORM model, I'd like to save some default values which are calculated based on other values. The best I could come up with is:

```
function save(){
    if( ! $this->loaded()){
        // Set values here
    }
    parent::save();
}
```

Does anybody know if there is a better/recommended way to do this, or should this be sufficient for most cases?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is good. The only improvement you could do is just replace your condition to:

```
if (!$this->_loaded) {
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe this is being too pedantic but is there any reason it's better to use protected '_loaded' rather than the higher level 'loaded()'? Or just a matter of code tidiness preference?

Comment: @jord: look at the first lines in `Kohana_ORM::__call()` method. There is just some useless (in your case) work.

Answer (score 1):

It`s very good question.

Unfortunnaly your way only possible.

Below ORM::create () function wich called from ORM::save().

```
public function create(Validation $validation = NULL)
{
  if ($this->_loaded)
    throw new Kohana_Exception('Cannot create :model model because it is already loaded.', array(':model' => $this->_object_name));

  // Require model validation before saving
  if ( ! $this->_valid OR $validation)
  {
    $this->check($validation);
  }

  $data = array();
  foreach ($this->_changed as $column)
  {
    // Generate list of column => values
    $data[$column] = $this->_object[$column];
  }

  if (is_array($this->_created_column))
  {
    // Fill the created column
    $column = $this->_created_column['column'];
    $format = $this->_created_column['format'];

    $data[$column] = $this->_object[$column] = ($format === TRUE) ? time() : date($format);
  }

  $result = DB::insert($this->_table_name)
  ->columns(array_keys($data))
  ->values(array_values($data))
  ->execute($this->_db);

  if ( ! array_key_exists($this->_primary_key, $data))
  {
    // Load the insert id as the primary key if it was left out
    $this->_object[$this->_primary_key] = $this->_primary_key_value = $result[0];
  }
  else
  {
    $this->_primary_key_value = $this->_object[$this->_primary_key];
  }

  // Object is now loaded and saved
  $this->_loaded = $this->_saved = TRUE;

  // All changes have been saved
  $this->_changed = array();
  $this->_original_values = $this->_object;

  return $this;
}
```

As you can see, there are no defaut values ...